# Creating different layout for different user types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As a background, I am currently creating a student database. I am working on the log in page portion of it. As of right now, I am able to show the different user type through a dropdown list and have users input their username and password. I am able to successfully log in the users with correct credentials and redirect them to a default layout under the _ViewStart.csthml. My problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to redirect them to a different page. In the code below, I was thinking to check for the user type that is selected by users and create separate layout for each of the user type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace LoginQuery
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=CHRIS\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FPSDD;Integrated Security=True";
            con.Open();
        }

        protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and PersonType='" + userType.SelectedValue + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(ds, "Person");
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (userType.SelectedValue == "Student")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Instructor")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Counselor")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Parent")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Principal")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Admin")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Counselor")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Instructor")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Counselor")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("");
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PersonType FROM Person where Username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(ds, "Person");

                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type. Please Try Again!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "Invalid User Type, Username or Password. Please Try Again!";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected void UserType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
            {
                if (userType.SelectedValue == "Student")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Teacher")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/teacher.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Counselor")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/counselor.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Parent")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/parent.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Principal")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/principal.png";
                }
                else if (userType.SelectedValue == "Admin")
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/admin.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    ImageDef.ImageUrl = "Images/student.png";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Under the _ViewStart.cshtml, I control the Layouts rendering by using _ViewStart file in the root directory of the Views folder.

```
@{
    var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    string cLayout = "";
    if (controller == "UsersController")
    {
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Students.cshtml";
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Parents.cshtml";
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Principal.cshtml";
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Instructor.cshtml";
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Counselors.cshtml";
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else if (controller == "")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Dashboard.cshtml";
    }
    Layout = cLayout;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to redirect the different user types to a different pages will be appreciated!

Comment: Your connection handling is all wrong. You should create and open the connection as late as possible, and close it as soon as possible. SqlConnection implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). The best way to work with it is to put it in a using statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created a different layout for different users and also have different user views. So it is very easy to add separate layout for different users.
When a user logged in to your system they will get different view pages.
You can define the corresponding layout of the user directly in the top of the view.

For example, add following code in the top of 'student' view.

```
@{
    Layout =  "~/Views/Shared/_Students.cshtml";
}
```

Likewise, view of the 'parents' will be:

```
@{
    Layout =  "~/Views/Shared/_Parents.cshtml";
}
```

Do it for each view page of different users. You will get a better result.

Answer (score 0):

You can define layout directly in the view.

Examples:

In the top of UsersController/Index.cshtml file (only for this view)

```
{
    Layout = "_Layout2"
}
```

And in _ViewStart.cshtml (default)

```
{
    Layout = "_Layout"
}
```

It is not necessary to pass the complete path of the file, the project will automatically search within the shared folder